# Text getting clipped when drawing using graphics.DrawString method

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing

I am using the graphics.MeasureString method to measure the text size. And based on the measured text size, I was the draw the string using the graphics.MeasureString. But in that I was using the StringFormat to measure and draw the string. But I found the text clipping problem in some text like "left".

Please find the code snippet below,

```
string text = "Left";
Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 9F);
StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);
SizeF size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, font, 100, format);
e.Graphics.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(10, 10, size.Width, size.Height), format);
```

Please find the text clipping while drawing in below screen shot,

[image]

Can you please suggest how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is your drawing space big enough? Where does your e reference to?

Comment: This is weird indeed. Note that the flag is not necessary unless you actually use a large, multiline Rectangle, so you can leave it off. Or you can add 1 to the width, which seems to all it needs !?!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I have removed the `StringFormat` from the code. It works.

```
string text = "Left";
Font font = new Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 9F);
//StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);
SizeF size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, font, 100);
e.Graphics.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(10, 10, size.Width, size.Height));
```

**Edit1**

I have modified the answer as per OP's request to use `StringFormat` enum.

```
string text = "Left";
Font font = new Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 9F);
StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);
SizeF size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, font, 100, format);
e.Graphics.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(10, 10, size.Width + 5, size.Height), format);
```

Comment: How should this even work when you have an undefined variable `format`?

Comment: @SkryptX sorry, I forget to remove it. I have modified the answer

Comment: Hi @BalagurunathanMarimuthu, I have using the above code in my control, in that I exposed some property to allow or ignore the wrap text. If i disable the wrap text, the text should not be wrapped into next line. So I must use the StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap) to achieve my requirement. So any possible way to solve this without removing the stringFormat?

Comment: @Jagadeesan Please see the modified answer.

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu, I can't able to manually increase the width. because this problem occurs in some fonts alone. So when increase the width manually will leads to some other problem.

Comment: @Jagadeesan so, you probably add those fonts in condition to add this extra width and leave others as it is.